# How To Create a File Dialog Using Python

Tags: python, file, user-interface, dialog, tk-toolkit

I started coding 3 days ago! So far it has been fun, but I have encoured my first road block.
I'm wanting to create a "FILE" button that performs all the same functions as it would in any other application: Open, Save, and Save as.
What I can do so far is click the file button to expose my three options.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def MyFiles():
    my_ListFile = Listbox(root, selectmode="single", bg="light grey", width=18, height=3, font=('Helvetica 10'))
    my_ListFile.place(x=0, y=27)
    # Additing items to list box
    my_ListFile.insert(END, "Open")
    my_ListFile.insert(END, "Save")
    my_ListFile.insert(END, "Save As")

def oneselect(event):
    listB = event.widget
    idx = int(listB.curselection()[0])
    value = w.get(idx)
    # if the value is open, then open the directory and close the listbox
    # if the value is Save, then save the current GUI and close the listbox
    #if the value is Save As, open directory and close list box

File = Button(root, text="File", command=MyFiles, width=15, font=('Helvetica 10')).place(x=1, y=1)

root.mainloop()
```

How can I click each option in the list to perform a different function? I'm attempting to build a GUI.

Comment: This sounds more like you are looking for a `Menu` and you might as well want to search for `filedialog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like below:

[image: File Dialog Screenshot]

You may be able to try something like below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

# create the root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Tkinter Dialog')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.geometry('300x150')

# helper function to select a file to open
def select_file():
    filetypes = (
        ('text files', '*.txt'),
        ('All files', '*.*')
    )
    filename = fd.askopenfilename(
        title='Open a file',
        initialdir='/',
        filetypes=filetypes)
    showinfo(
        title='Selected File',
        message=filename
    )

# helper function to save a file
def file_save():
    filetypes = (
    ('text files', '*.txt'),
    ('All files', '*.*')
    )
    f = fd.asksaveasfile(
        title='Save a file',
        mode='w', 
        defaultextension=".txt")
    if f is None: # asksaveasfile return `None` if dialog closed with "cancel".
        return

# helper function to save a file
def file_save_as():
    filetypes = (
    ('text files', '*.txt'),
    ('All files', '*.*')
    )
    f = fd.asksaveasfile(
        title='Save a file',
        mode='w', 
        defaultextension=".txt")
    if f is None: # asksaveasfile return `None` if dialog closed with "cancel".
        return

def Click(e, var):
    def VG(var):
        select_file()
    def G(var):
        file_save()
    def P(var):
        file_save_as()
    e.widget.focus()
    nclst=[(' Open', lambda var = var: VG(var)),
            (' Save', lambda var = var: G(var)),
            (' Save As', lambda var = var: P(var)),]

    my_menu = tk.Menu(None, tearoff=0, takefocus=0)
    for (txt, cmd) in nclst:
            my_menu.add_command(label=txt, command=cmd)
    my_menu.tk_popup(e.x_root+40, e.y_root+10,entry="0")

l_var = tk.StringVar()
lab = tk.Label(root, textvariable = l_var, width = 10)
l_var.set("File")
lab.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e, var = l_var: Click(e, var)) 
lab.pack()

# run the application
root.mainloop()
```

Note that you'll want to modify the specific functionality of the file open, save, and save as methods to match your specific needs - But this may help in getting started